# Can someone explain this ruby code

Tags: ruby

Can someone please explain how << is used in this recursive function?

Specifically, the "<<" in

### return ( letter * (self / value)) << (self % value).roman if value <= self

```
    class Fixnum
      ROMAN_NUMBERS = {
        1000 => "M",  
         900 => "CM",  
         500 => "D",  
         400 => "CD",
         100 => "C",  
          90 => "XC",  
          50 => "L",  
          40 => "XL",  
          10 => "X",  
            9 => "IX",  
            5 => "V",  
            4 => "IV",  
            1 => "I",  
      }

    def roman
        return '' if self == 0
        ROMAN_NUMBERS.each do |value, letter|
          return ( letter * (self / value)) << (self % value).roman if value <= self
        end
        return (self % value).roman
      end
    end
```

I've only ever seen "<<" used to push an object onto an array, and I don't feel like that is happening here.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: @limelights it returns the Roman value for a given `fixnum`: `123.roman` returns `CXXIII`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a String concatenation operator. See the [Ruby String class docs.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) In general, in Ruby and often other programing languages, the `<<` operator represents some sort of concatenation, appending, or pushing on to some already existing data.

Answer (score 1):

<< is also defined in the String class: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C

```
1.9.3-p547 :003 > str = "M" * 3
 => "MMM" 
1.9.3-p547 :005 > str << "hello"
 => "MMMhello"
```